# Automatically Assign Location for Comment in PGFPlots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pdftex

I have a pgfplot that create line plot, I would like to add a comment to one of those points on line. I have a LaTeX code that can work to add comment at a specific location.

[image: Pgfplot with comment]

But, Sometimes, because of the data, the comment overlaps with the line plot and it does not look very professional, as shown below.

[image: pdfplot latex with comment overlapped]

Is there a way to add a comment on pgfplots, that uses **white space in the plot windows to add a comment**, so that it does not overlaps with the data line/curve? I don't mind reducing the font size of comment to quite small, so that it fits the white space.

Here is the fully functional LaTeX code.

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\setbeamersize{text margin left=1mm,text margin right=1mm} 

% remove beamer's navigation bar at the bottom
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty

%\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
\usepackage[sf,bf]{titlesec}
\usepackage{lmodern}

% this adds a margin or padding for table rows.
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}

% Define dark green as default
\definecolor{green}{RGB}{0,128,0}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\begin{document}
  
  % used by archived code
  \pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{
  date, sales, target
  2012Q1, 1.272, 0.894
  2012Q2, 1.948, 0.954
  2012Q3, 0.355, 0.895
  2012Q4, 0.909, 1.045
  2013Q1, 2.681, 0.896
  2013Q2, 0.277, 0.665
  2013Q3, 0.841, 0.908
  2013Q4, 1.130, 1.575
  2014Q1, 3.265, 1.091
  2014Q2, 1.132, 1.091
  2014Q3, 1.548, 1.091
  2014Q4, 0.392, 1.091
}\datatable
  
  
  
  \newpage
  
%   \textbf{plot with comment}
  
  \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[
        title=Plot Title,
        xlabel=Quarter,
        ylabel=Sales,
        width=14cm,
        height=4cm,
        grid=major,
        xtick=data,
        xticklabels from table={\datatable}{date}, 
        x tick label style={anchor=north},
        label style={font=\tiny},
        %           xticklabel style={font=\tiny},
        xticklabel style={scale=0.5},
        yticklabel style={font=\tiny}   
        ]
        \addplot [sharp plot, red, mark=*] table [x expr=\coordindex, 
        y=target] {\datatable};
        \addplot [sharp plot, blue, mark=*] table [x expr=\coordindex, 
        y=sales] {\datatable};
        
        \node[pin=130:This is the comment,draw=black] at (axis cs:6,1) {};
        
        
        \legend{Target, Actual}
      \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{figure}
  
  
  
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think more information is needed. Why can you not just place the comment manually? Are there hundred/thousands of plots? -or is the plot randomly generated every time? What about the comment text itself - why do you not need to change that manually? Is it the same every time?

Comment: @hpekristiansen, thanks. Yes. I am trying to automate weekly update report. I create the number of plots (though not in hundreds, but about 20ish). Currently, I take a screenshot and then add a comment in PowerPoint to point out interested data points. The comment text will be different each time, but I can have a text limit, so it won't be very long. Just a line or two. Thank you.